# Suggestion for optimizing Script to "Paste Values Only" based on matching today's date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm hoping that someone may be able to provide some advice regarding this script that I wrote below.  I have a spreadsheet with a large number of Sheets in it and would like to "Copy/Paste Values Only" to several columns based on the date inside the sheet matching today's date (with the intent of running the script every day at a certain time).

I searched through some past topics for insight into similar formatting types but still can't seem to get it to run properly; any input is appreciated!

```
//Loops through individual sheets and checks to find current day's tab.  Once found it copy/paste specials the values only to lock the day's values.  
function lockDaysValues (){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var todaysDate = new Date(); 
    var todaysDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"PST","MM-dd-yyyy") //formats to fit 
    current tab name date titles of MM/DD/YYYY
    var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 
     for(var x=0; x<sheets.length; x++){
      checkSheets = sheets[x].getRange('C2').getValue();  
        if(checkSheets=='todaysDateFormatted'){
          ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('C5:D').activate();
          ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('C5:D').copyTo(ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('C5:D'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
      }else{
          break; 
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with this particular code? Be more specific on what is not working and what is the error message you are getting. If you are looking for code improvement/suggestions then please post this question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your source and destination for the copyTo are the same range

Answer (score 0):

comparing date values for start of day for each date

```
function lockDaysValues (){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dt=new Date(); 
  var dtv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets(); 
  for(var x=0;x<sheets.length;x++){
    sdt=new Date(sheets[x].getRange('C2').getValue());//presume this is date  
    sdtv=new Date(sdt.getFullYear(),sdt.getMonth(),sdt.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(sdtv==dtv){
      //source and destination seem to be the same so not sure what you want here
      sheets[x].getRange(5,3,sheets[x].getLastRow()-4,2).copyTo(sheets[x].getRange(5,3,sheets[x].getLastRow()-4,2), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    }else{
      break; 
    }
  }
}
```